# button still in the focus status once close the Angular UI Bootstrap modal dialogue window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

How to avoid the `:focus` status from the button or link once the modal dialogue window opened ?

The clicked button still in the `:focus` status once closed the Angular UI Bootstrap modal dialogue window whether `$uibModalInstance.close();` or `$uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');`

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/3w65mjnt/

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']).controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function($scope, $uibModal, $log) {
  $scope.open = function() {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      size: 'sm',
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'
    });
    modalInstance.result.then(function() {
      console.log("close");
    }, function() {
      console.log("cancelled");
    });
  };
}).controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
  $scope.ok = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.close();
  };
  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.0.3.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm modal</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non similique facilis necessitatibus. Sequi quos possimus quidem blanditiis nobis ipsam vitae amet unde eos id. Beatae natus nemo dolores minima ullam!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </script>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open Modal WIndow</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle ?

Comment: @Raviteja there you go  https://jsfiddle.net/3w65mjnt/

Comment: is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/3w65mjnt/1/) okay for you ?